# Vector of strings returning null characters

Tags: c++, string, vector

I am writing a text editor using ncurses, and I want to make the program save what I wrote -into a text file. What I currently have saves what I write but I get a bunch of null characters between words... also sometimes the characters saved are different to what I type. I am assuming it has something to do with the way the vector stores the strings? Or perhaps the pushback function leaves null characters behind?

main.cpp:

```
#include<iostream> //g++ *.cpp -lncurses -o run
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
#include<ncurses.h>
#include<vector>
#include"draw.h"
using namespace std;
vector <string> file;
int nWords = 1;

int save(){
    ofstream save;
    save.open("/home/adam/editorText", ofstream::out);

    for(int i=0; i<nWords; i++)
    {
        save.write(file[i].c_str(), sizeof(file[i]));
    }
}

int colourCheck(){
    if(has_colors() == false){
        endwin();
        cout<< "ERROR: your terminal does not support colours\n";
        cout<< "exiting \n";
        return 1;
        }
    else{
        return 0;
        }
}

int init()
{
    initscr();
    raw();
    keypad(stdscr, TRUE);
    noecho();
    start_color();
}
bool on = true;

int main()
{
    string word = "";
    const char * color = "blue";
    init();
    colourCheck();
    drawGraphics draw;
    draw.setDrawBox(0, 3, 0, 20);
    draw.fillDrawBox(1, COLOR_BLACK, COLOR_BLUE);
    while(on){
        int chr= getch();

        switch(chr){

            case(32):                    //ascii value of 'space'
                file.push_back(word);
                printw("%c", chr);//
                word = "";
                nWords++;         //every time space bar is pressed: nwords++
                break;

            case(27):                 //ascii value of 'ESC'
                file.push_back(word);
                save();
                on = false;
                break;

            case(15):

            default:
                printw("%c", chr);
                word.push_back(chr);
                break;

        }


    }
    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you already debug your code, to narrow the problem source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is this:

```
sizeof(file[i])
```

The sizeof() is a compile-time value.  Given that, how is sizeof() going to know what the length of the string is at runtime?

You want to get the length of the string, and for that you use:

```
file[i].size()
```